# Temporarily disable rotation (while an animation runs)

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, autorotate

I’m trying to temporarily disable rotation of an iPad while an animation is running. I assumed the correct way to do this was to implement `shouldAutorotate` in the view controller in question and return `YES` or `NO` based on whether that animation is running (I have a `BOOL` for that).

Turns out, `shouldAutorotate` is never called, it’s just rotating anyway.

The view controller needs to support all interface orientations (I’ve tried implementing `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and returning `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` just to be sure, but it made no difference), but it just needs to be locked into the current one while this little 0.5s animation takes place.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Ugh, rotation is always a pain in the butt.... In the newer iOS versions i think the rotating functionality ask the base view controller in the higherarchy, generally that is a UINavigationController, or UITabeBarController or any root view controller. Then that method would be called... the way to get around it is calling something like [self.visibleController shouldAutoRotate]; but i don't have the exact answer.. or i would answer

Answer (score 2):

Is your view controller part of the UINavigationController's stack? If so, you could create a custom subclass of UINavigationController, override shouldAutorotate in your implementation, and then forward that call to any visible view controllers.

Comment: It’s already part of a custom `UINavigationController` stack. Implementing `shouldAutorotate` there results in it not being called either.

Comment: this might be a dumb question, but is this navigation controller the root of your application, such as in app delegate you would normally have [self.window setRootViewController:myNavigationController]; that might be a view controller which then would get all the rotation calls instead

Comment: Yes, it is. Besides, in iOS7 aren’t rotation methods automatically forwarded to child view controllers?

Comment: Nope. Definitely not. You'll need to call [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate] to forward the call. If that's not working, then something else is going on and we may need to see some more code. I'm currently working on an application that employs the exact approach and it's working fine.